# Como transformar variáveis numéricas em strings no R (0=NÂO e 1=SIM)?

Tags: r, variáveis

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hO2u.png)Eu tenho uma planilha de dados onde 0=Não e 1=Sim. Quando eu tento criar uma tabela dessa variável aparece o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]]

Como faço para que a função prop.table a a função pie do gráfico de pizzas reconheça essas variáveis como SIM e NÂO?

Comment: Você deve ter algum `NA` no seu vetor, faça `sum(is.na(rehab.1$IAM1))` para confirmar se está tudo certo. Outra coisa que você precisa corrigir é que antes do prop.table() é preciso usar o table() então seria `prop.table(table(rehab.1$IAM1))`

Comment: Não entendi ao certo a questão, transformar uma variável numérica em uma string pode ser feito com `as.character()`. Tens como exemplificar melhor sua duvida?

Comment: Obrigado Andrelrms, estava errada a forma que usei a função prop.table(), realmente faltou usar o table. Eu imaginava que isto estava acontecendo porque eu deveria transformar 0 em NÂO e 1 em SIM, mas vejo que não tem nada a ver. Comecei a estudar R agora e ainda estou apanhando com essas coisas básicas. Valeu, grande abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Eu iria sugerir fechar a questão, mas como pode ser algo útil para outros usuários vou colocar aqui dois conhecimentos úteis que resolveriam o problema e apresentam um conceito importante sobre o uso do R.

Inicialmente vou gerar um exemplo reprodutível de um vetor de zeros e uns com 20 números.

```
set.seed(1)
vetor <- rbinom(n = 20, prob = 0.5, size = 1)
```

Para contar os zeros e uns basta usar o comando table:

```
table(vetor)
```

que resulta

```
 0  1 
 9 11
```

Assim ao usar o prob.table() nesse resultado:

```
prop.table(table(vetor))
```

obtemos

```
0    1 
0.45 0.55
```

Até aqui todos são números. Digamos que você queira que os resultado fiquem exatamente como "SIM" e "NÃO". Nesse caso o ideal é converter a variável em fator (factor).

```
vetor <- factor(vetor)
```

tal que agora o fator tem dois níveis: "0" e "1". Veja que agora não são mais números, mas níveis de um fator. Você pode obter os níveis de um fator por meio do comando levels().

```
levels(vetor)
```

resultado em

```
[1] "0" "1"
```

Para deixar como "SIM" e "NÃO" basta mudar o nome dos níveis para "SIM" e "NÃO" na ordem que em que eles são apresentados.

```
levels(vetor) <- c("NÃO", "SIM")
```

tal que agora zero é não e um é sim.

```
print(vetor)

[1] NÃO NÃO SIM SIM NÃO SIM SIM SIM SIM NÃO NÃO NÃO SIM NÃO SIM NÃO
[17] SIM SIM NÃO SIM
Levels: NÃO SIM
```

Os comando table() e prop.table() vai funcionar como anteriormente.